# Numbers not registering as strings in array

Tags: php, html, web

OK, so I have a form for a website that I'm trying to create. I'm trying to store the user input from HTML into string values to be displayed in PHP. The trouble is, when I type number values where I'm supposed to, it is not recognized by PHP. This works for the "Radio button" type input, but not for plain text. I have included code for both pages of the site.
    
    
    
        Tower design centre - Build your own tower here!

```
<body>
    <h1 style="font-family:impact; font-size:72; color:silver;">Tower Design Centre</h1>
    <p style="font-family:courier; font-size:22; color:blue;">Build your own tower here!</p>
    <p style="font-family:arial; font-size:12; color:black;"> Welcome to Tower Builder! Please select shapes and dimensions for the different parts of your tower.</p>

    <form action="testfile_post.php" method="post" target="_blank" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        Select pillar base shape:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="tBase" value="Circle" checked>Circle<br>
        <input type="radio" name="tBase" value="Triangle" checked>Triangle<br>
        <input type="radio" name="tBase" value="Rectangle" checked>Rectangle<br>
        <input type="radio" name="tBase" value="Pentagon" checked>Pentagon<br>
        <input type="radio" name="tBase" value="Hexagon" checked>Hexagon<br>
        <input type="radio" name="tBase" value="Heptagon" checked>Heptagon<br>
        <input type="radio" name="tBase" value="Octagon" checked>Octagon<br>
        <!--Set variable tBase equal to user's option. -->

        <fieldset> <!-- Use height/width to make fieldset border smaller in order to fit picture of tower being built.-->
            <legend>Pillar dimensions:</legend>
            Height:<br>
            <input type="text" name="tHeight"><br>
            <!-- User must input height option. Text should only be positive integers greater than zero. Set variable tHeight equal to user's input. Must comply with ratios.-->
            Width:<br>
            <input type="text" name="tWidth"><br>
            <!-- Same constraints as height apply. Set variable tWidth equal to user's input.-->
            Depth:<br>
            <input type="text" name="tDepth"><br>
            <!-- Same constraints as height and width. Set variable tDepth equal to user's input.-->
            Slant:<br>
            <input type="text" name="tSlant"><br>
            <!--Set variable tSlant equal to user input. tSlant cannot exceed -45 or 45. If it does, throw error message and do not allow user to continue. 
        Neg. and pos. integers, as well as zero, may be used. If tSlant >= 35 or <= -35, throw Leaning Tower communication.-->
        </fieldset>

        Select pod shape:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="pShape" value="Circle" checked>Circle<br>
        <input type="radio" name="pShape" value="Triangle" checked>Triangle<br>
        <input type="radio" name="pShape" value="Rectangle" checked>Rectangle<br>
        <input type="radio" name="pShape" value="Pentagon" checked>Pentagon<br>
        <input type="radio" name="pShape" value="Hexagon" checked>Hexagon<br>
        <input type="radio" name="pShape" value="Heptagon" checked>Heptagon<br>
        <input type="radio" name="pShape" value="Octagon" checked>Octagon<br>
        <!-- Set variable pShape equal to user's option. -->

        <fieldset> <!-- Use height/width to make fieldset border smaller in order to fit picture of tower being built.-->
            <legend>Pod dimensions:</legend>
            Height:<br>
            <input type="text" name="pHeight"><br>
            <!--Text should only be positive integers greater than zero. Set variable pHeight equal to user's input.-->
            Width:<br>
            <input type="text" name="pWidth"><br>
            <!-- Same constraints as height apply. Set variable pWidth equal to user's input.-->
            Depth:<br>
            <input type="text" name="pDepth"><br>
            <!-- Same constraints as height and width. Set variable pDepth equal to user's input.-->
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Pod placement:</legend>
        <input type="text" name="pPlace1"><br>
        <!--Set variable pPlace1 equal to user's input. -->
        out of<br>
        <input type="text" name="pPlace2"><br>
        <!--Set variable pPlace2 equal to user's input.-->
    </fieldset>
    <!-- Do not let pPlace1 exceed pPlace2.-->

    Select spindle base shape:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sShape" value="Circle" checked>Circle<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sShape" value="Triangle" checked>Triangle<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sShape" value="Rectangle" checked>Rectangle<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sShape" value="Pentagon" checked>Pentagon<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sShape" value="Hexagon" checked>Hexagon<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sShape" value="Heptagon" checked>Heptagon<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sShape" value="Octagon" checked>Octagon<br>
    <!--Set variable sShape equal to user's option.-->

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Spindle dimensions:</legend>
        Height:<br>
        <input type="text" name="tHeight"><br>
        <!-- Text should only be positive integers greater than zero. Set variable tHeight equal to user's input. Must comply with ratios.-->
        Width:<br>
        <input type="text" name="tWidth"><br>
        <!-- Same constraints as height apply. Set variable tWidth equal to user's input.-->
        Depth:<br>
        <input type="text" name="tDepth"><br>
        <!-- Same constraints as height and width. Set variable tDepth equal to user's input.-->
        Slant:<br>
        <input type="text" name="tSlant"><br>
        <!-- Text can be both positive and negative integers, as well as zero. Cannot exceed -80 or 80 degrees. Set variable tSlant equal to user's input.-->
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

What I have so far in the PHP code:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST) ?><br>
    Pillar base shape: <?php echo $_POST["tBase"]; ?><br>
    Pillar dimensions: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["tHeight"])." x ".htmlspecialchars($_POST["tWidth"])." x ".htmlspecialchars($_POST["tDepth"]); ?><br>
```

So far, when these results are combined, I can see a character count in the var_dump array for the shapes (i.e.  ["tBase"]=> string(7) "Octagon"), but when it comes to numerical values, there is no character count, meaning that the numerical values are not getting through. Can anyone help me out on this? Thank you.

Comment: Good call. I checked over my code and it turns out I do have duplicates. ...But even with the variable change, it's still showing up as 0 x 0 x 0.

Comment: OK, I didn't need you to do my whole code for me, but I took what I needed from the code. Thank you. I'll be able to get everything else done on my own, using what I did take as an example.

Answer (score 0):

[See `inval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

> **Description**
>
> ```
> int intval ( mixed $var [, int $base = 10 ] )
> ```
>
> Returns the integer value of `var`, using the specified base for the conversion (the default is base 10). `intval()` should not be used on objects, as doing so will emit an `E_NOTICE` level error and return `1`.

So if your input is `$_POST["value"]`, you can get the integer value with:

```
$integer_value = intval( $_POST["value"] );
```

Comment: I copy/pasted the line of code into my existing code. It threw the following message when I put it in: Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tower\testfile_post.php on line 9. And the same thing happenedas before. Where exactly should I put this code?

Comment: $_POST["value"] is a placeholder. replace "value" with the name of the key (from the form) that corresponds to the actual value you're trying to use

Comment: OK, I tried this out. Now it registers as "0 x 0 x 0" on the result screen, no mater what number I type in. Anyone know why this may be?